# Linked list single class vs multiple classes

Tags: linked-list

In my second term as an computer science student almost the whole term we have focused on writing linked lists in different variations(stack, queue, ...). The design of these lists always came down to this

```
class List<T> {
    class ListElement {
        T value;
        ListElement next;
    }
    ListElement root;
}
```

with variations to which methods were implemented and how they worked (I have left out constructors and properties for simplicity here).

Some day I started learning scala and focusing on functional programming. This also came to the point where a linked list was written but in a different *style* of implementation.

```
class List[T]( head: T, tail: List[T])
```

Despite the different syntax and immutability this is in my opinion a different aproach.
And I thought to myself "Well you could have implemented lists the same way in C# or Java with one `class` less than the aproach you learned".

I can see why you would implement a linked list like that in a functional language where recursion is not as *dangerous* as in C# or Java because at least for my way of thinking a recursive implementation of all the usual methods on a linked list for this design is very intuitive.

**What I do not understand is why are linked lists in C# or Java typically implemented in the first fashion when you could implement them the other way with less code but equal verbosity?** (I am not talking about the implementation of lists in the libraries of the language but about the lists you typically write as a programmer to be)

<strike>The only benefit I can see with the first approach is that you can hide the implementation from the user a bit better but is this the reason and also is this worth the additional `class`?</strike>
I wouldn't even need to expose my implementation to the user as I could still implement my list internally different and maybe only have chosen to have a constructor like that and provide functionality to retreive the first element of the list as `head` and also the rest as `tail`.

Comment: Assuming no universal nullability, you still need multiple classes in the latter case. Scala solves it like [this](https://gist.github.com/rightfold/ef1faf5415655d3900c2).

Comment: @rightfold That is certainly true but theoretically you could just set `tail` to `null` or in the case of scala you could have used `Option[List[T]]`. I know that using `null` is bad but in the C#-world it seems to be widely accepted(at least in code I had to work with or lectures I heard). Also in the first case you also need a value to set root to if the list is empty.

Comment: `Option` is a class, so you still have two classes. :)

Comment: @rightfold The point was that if you say we need a `class` for the empty `tail` or even the empty list we would also need that `class` in the first design as there is also the possibility of an empty list and we need a value that `root` points to. So we still have one `class` less in the second aproach.

Comment: @rightfold also you could count `Option` as three classes because of `Some` and `None` ^^

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for them to be "implemented in the first fashion" as you mentioned include

**Performance.**

Time and space complexity are the two most important concerns while writing algorithms or implementing data structures that support operations like search and sort. As you have mentioned, the lists created the recursive way aren't mutable! The very purpose of creating a list is attaining faster operations on that. So designers prefer the 'first fashion'.

**Object orientation**

While solving real world problems, the initial object oriented analysis and design (OOAD) matter a lot. With an object modelling that closely resembles the real world objects/things as much as they can, designers can achieve better solutions. The recursive approach seems to miss out this aspect

**Scalability**

Designers of APIs/Libraries keep scalability in mind when they draft the designs. A code written in the 'first fashion' is much more scalable, and easy to comprehend.

**Other design concerns**

This is not an exhaustive list of the reasons in any way. There are so many other factors and experience based learning that exist in the programming folklore, that lead to the choice of the first fashion.

Comment: I don't see why one of the implementations should be better from a performance perspective. I could very well implement a list in the second fashion that is mutable as long as my member variables are mutable.
From an object oriented perspective I also don't think one resembles the real world more closely than the other as both designs have an object at the root/head and a next/tail which contains all other elements.
Also could you please elaborate why the first aproach is more scalable?